# yesod SqlBackendKey to Text

Tags: yesod

Is it possible to convert/parse SqlBackendKey to Real Text?

e.g Model

```
UserInfo
    fullName Text
    ageBracket Text Maybe
    gender Text
    createdOn UTCTime default=now()
    updatedOn UTCTime Maybe
    deriving Show

User
    userInfoId UserInfoId
    username Text
    password Text
    UniqueUsername username
    deriving Show
```

on my code:

```
-- let say the output of this
-- userInfoId  = 1 -- this is a
-- username = admin
-- paswword = admin
userData <- runDB $ selectFirst [UserUsername ==. uname , UsersPassword ==. pword] [LimitTo 1]


case userData of
            Nothing -> ....
            Just (Entity _ u) -> do
                let userInfoId = T.pack (show (userUserInfoId u))
                $(logInfo) userInfoId 
                .....
```

the output of the $(logInfo) userInfoId

```
[INFO] UserInfoKey {unUserInfoKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 1}}
```

I only need the number "1" (One).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fromSqlKey](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2.4/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#v:fromSqlKey).

```
fromSqlKey (userUserInfoId u)
```